# Mock @ngrx/store in angular 2

Tags: testing, ngrx-store

I am using store in my application like below and it works fine.

```
export class NavigationComponent {
  navigationLinks$: Observable<Navigation[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.navigationLinks$ = this.store.select('navigation')
                                .map((result: State) => result.navigationLinks);
   }
```

Now, I am trying to create a unit test and want to mock this store. This is what i am doing:

**1. Creating the Mock Store**
Creating a mock store which will return mock data when this.store.select('') is called. The mockdata returns a property of array type called navigationLinks.

```
class StoreMock {
  public dispatch(obj) {
    console.log('dispatching from the mock store!')
  }

  public select(obj) {
    console.log('selecting from the mock store!');

    return Observable.of([
       { 'navigaitonLinks$': [{ 'name': 'Help', hasChild: false}] }
    ])
  }
}
```

**2. BeforeEach blocks**

```
describe('NavigationComponent', () => {
  let component: NavigationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavigationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NavigationComponent],
      providers: [{provide: Store, useClass: StoreMock}],
      imports: [
        StoreModule.provideStore(reducers)
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

**3. My test**
I know this test will fail as per the expect statement but I am not able to populate the navigationLinks$ property with my mock data.

```
 it(`should create the navigation with 'Help' link`, () => {

    let navLinks: any[];
    component.navigationLinks$.subscribe();
    console.log(navLinks); // This should print my mockdata so i can assert it
    expect(component.navigationLinks$).toEqual('Help');
  });
```

The console.log prints undefined and is not able to read the data that MockStore select() is returning. Is there something extra I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and I just return the object with Observable.of() function.

```
return Observable.of([
   { 'navigaitonLinks$': [{ 'name': 'Help', hasChild: false}] }
])
```

to

```
return Observable.of([{ 'name': 'Help', hasChild: false}, {}, {} ... ]);
```

This will populate your Observable object :

```
it(`should create the navigation with 'Help' link`, () => {
    component.navigationLinks$.subscribe((links) => {
    console.log(links); // This should print an array of Links
  });
});
```